# How to collect URL links for pages that are not numerically ordered

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

When URLs are ordered in a numeric order, it's simple to fetch all the articles in a given website.

However, when we have a website such as https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti where there are articles with URLs like

`https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/10-iula-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-i-ministra-inostrannyh-del-mongolii-n-enhtajv?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1`

How do I fetch all the article URLs on this website? Where there's no numeric order or whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's order to that chaos.

If you take a good look at the source code you'll surely notice the `next` button. If you click it and inspect the url (it's long, I know) you'll see there's a value at the very end of it - `_cur=1`. This is the number of the current page you're at.

The problem, however, is that you don't know how many pages there are, right? But, you can programmatically keep checking for a url in the next button and stop when there are no more pages to go to.

Meanwhile, you can scrape for article urls while you're at the current page.

Here's how to do it:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


url = "https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti"

next_page_xpath = '//*[@class="pager lfr-pagination-buttons"]/li[2]/a/@href'
article_xpath = '//*[@class="title"]/a/@href'


def get_page(url):
    return requests.get(url).content


def extractor(page, xpath):
    return html.fromstring(page).xpath(xpath)


def head_option(values):
    return next(iter(values), None)


articles = []
while True:
    page = get_page(url)
    print(f"Checking page: {url}")

    articles.extend(extractor(page, article_xpath))

    next_page = head_option(extractor(page, next_page_xpath))

    if next_page == 'javascript:;':
        break

    url = next_page

print(f"Scraped {len(articles)}.")
# print(articles)
```

This gets you `216` article urls. If you want to see the article urls, just uncomment the last line - `# print(articles)`

Here's a sample of `2`:

```
['https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/24-avgusta-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-ministrom-energetiki-mongolii-n-tavinbeh?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1', 'https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/19-avgusta-2020-goda-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-zamestitelem-ministra-inostran?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1']
```